# Vaadin separating tabs in a v.tabsheet using CSS

Tags: css, vaadin, spacing

How can I simply space out the width between each tab in a vaadin tabsheet? I have looked at the v-tabsheet spacetd but that CSS is not meant for this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably accomplish this by adding padding-right on the v-tabsheet-tabitemcell selector. This will cause the spacing of the tabs to grow, but you will need to update the background images to make it look good.

A background for the entire tabsheet header can be applied on the ".v-tabsheet-tabs tr" selector.